# Java ScrollPane on Buffered Image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, bufferedimage

So I have 4 classes, in my paint program and I am trying to add scrollbars to the canvas so that I can scroll around, When I make my buffered Image it is set to the size of the desktop, but the JFrame is only I think 700 or so pixels so as you expand or resize you are still on canvas. But I cant figure out how to add a JScrollPane to the buffered image so I can scroll around.

//**MAIN**//

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Main 
{
    public static int choice;

     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
            Board.getInstance();


     }
}
```

**//FRAME//**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Calvin Moss
 */
public class Board extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

     public static Board inst;

    Board()
    {


         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         Container c = getContentPane();
         c.add(Menu.getInstance(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
         getContentPane().add(Drawing.getInstance(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

         Drawing.getInstance().add(new JScrollPane());

         setSize(1200, 800);
         setBackground(Color.WHITE);
         setVisible(true);


         JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
         setJMenuBar(menuBar);
         JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
         menuBar.add(help);
         JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
         help.add(about);
         about.addActionListener(this);
    }


public static Board getInstance()
    {
        if(inst == null)
           inst = new Board();
         return inst;
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (e.getActionCommand().equals("About"))
        {
            JFrame about = new JFrame("About");
            about.setSize(300, 300);
            JButton picture = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/TehRobot/Desktop/Logo.png"));
            about.add(picture);
            about.setVisible(true);
        }

}


}
```

//**MENUPANEL**//

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


/**
 *
 * @author Calvin Moss
 */
public class Menu extends JPanel implements MouseListener, ActionListener{

    public static Color bgColor = null;
    public static int stroke = 0;
    public static Menu instance;
    private JButton clear;
    private JButton line;
    private JButton color;
    private JButton erase;
    private JButton pen;
    public static boolean once = true;
    public static BufferedImage buf = new BufferedImage(50,25,2);
    public static Graphics2D gr = buf.createGraphics();
    public static BufferedImage buf2 = new BufferedImage(50,25,2);
    public static Graphics2D gr2 = buf2.createGraphics();
    public static BufferedImage buf3 = new BufferedImage(50,25,2);
    public static Graphics2D gr3 = buf3.createGraphics();
    public static BufferedImage buf1 = new BufferedImage(50,25,2);
    public static Graphics2D gr1 = buf1.createGraphics();
    Menu()
    {
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        TitledBorder titledBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Toolbox");
        setBorder(titledBorder);


        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
        }
;


       clear = new JButton("Clear");
       clear.setActionCommand("Clear");
       clear.addActionListener(this);

       pen = new JButton("Pen");
       pen.setActionCommand("Pen");
       pen.addActionListener(this);

       erase = new JButton("Erase");
       erase.setActionCommand("e");
       erase.addActionListener(this);

       color = new JButton("Color");
       color.setActionCommand("Color");
       color.addActionListener(this);

       ImageIcon ir2 = new ImageIcon(buf3);
       JButton emptyR = new JButton(ir2);
       emptyR.addActionListener(this);
       emptyR.setActionCommand("ER");

       ImageIcon ir1 = new ImageIcon(buf2);
       JButton emptyO = new JButton(ir1);
       emptyO.addActionListener(this);
       emptyO.setActionCommand("EO");

       ImageIcon ir = new ImageIcon(buf);
       JButton fillR = new JButton(ir);
       fillR.addActionListener(this);
       fillR.setActionCommand("FR");

       ImageIcon io = new ImageIcon(buf1);
       JButton fillO = new JButton(io);
       fillO.addActionListener(this);
       fillO.setActionCommand("FO");


       line = new JButton("Line");
       line.setActionCommand("L");
       line.addActionListener(this);


       JButton button6 = new JButton("Line");
       button6.addActionListener(this);
       JRadioButton thin = new JRadioButton("Thin Line");
       thin.addActionListener(this);
       JRadioButton medium = new JRadioButton("Medium Line");
       medium.addActionListener(this);
       JRadioButton thick = new JRadioButton("Thick Line");
       thick.addActionListener(this);

        ButtonGroup lineOption = new ButtonGroup( );
        lineOption.add(thin);
        lineOption.add(medium);
        lineOption.add(thick);

        add(clear);
        add(erase);
        add(color);
        add(pen);
        add(line);
        add(thin);
        add(medium);
        add(thick);
        add(emptyR);
        add(emptyO);
        add(fillR);
        add(fillO);
        buttonGraphics();
        once = false;

    }


    public static Menu getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
           instance =  new Menu();
        return instance;
    }
    public static void buttonGraphics()
    {
        if (once == true)
        {
            gr.setColor(Color.RED);
            gr1.setColor(Color.RED);
            gr2.setColor(Color.RED);
            gr3.setColor(Color.RED);
        }else

        gr3.setColor(bgColor);
        gr3.drawRect(0, 0, 48, 23);
        gr2.setColor(bgColor);
        gr2.drawOval(0, 0, 47, 23);
        gr.setColor(bgColor);
        gr.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 23);
        gr1.setColor(bgColor);
        gr1.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 25);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Clear"))
        {
        Drawing.getInstance().clear();
        repaint();
        }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("e"))
    {
        Main.choice = 8;
        Drawing.getInstance().draw();
    }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Color"))
        {
        bgColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(this,"Choose Background Color", getBackground());
        gr.setColor(bgColor);
        gr1.setColor(bgColor);
        gr2.setColor(bgColor);
        gr3.setColor(bgColor);
        Main.choice = 7;
        buttonGraphics();
        repaint();
        Drawing.getInstance().draw();
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("L"))
        {
        Drawing.getInstance().FoE = 2;
        Main.choice = 1;
        repaint();
        }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("FR"))
        {
        Drawing.getInstance().FoE = 2;
        Main.choice = 2;
        repaint();
        }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("EO"))
        {
        Drawing.getInstance().FoE = 2;
        Main.choice = 3;
        repaint();
        }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("FO"))
        {
        Drawing.getInstance().FoE = 2;
        Main.choice = 4;
        repaint();
        }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("ER"))
        {
        Drawing.getInstance().FoE = 2;
        Main.choice = 5;

        repaint();
        }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Thin Line"))
      {
      stroke = 0;
      Drawing.getInstance().eraserHeight = 5;
      Drawing.getInstance().eraserWidth = 5;
      }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Medium Line"))
        {
        stroke = 1;
          Drawing.getInstance().eraserHeight = 15;
          Drawing.getInstance().eraserWidth = 15;
        }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Thick Line"))
        {
        stroke = 2;
          Drawing.getInstance().eraserHeight = 25;
          Drawing.getInstance().eraserWidth = 25;
        }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Pen"))
    {

        Main.choice = 10;
        Drawing.getInstance().draw();

    }


}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}



}
```

//**DRAWING CANVAS PANEL**//

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


/**
 *
 * @author Calvin Moss
 */
public class Drawing extends JPanel implements MouseListener, ActionListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    public int x1, x2 ,y1, y2;
    public static Drawing instance;
    public int FoE;
    public int eraserWidth = 15;
    public int eraserHeight = 15;

    BufferedImage grid;
    static Graphics2D gc;




    Drawing()
    {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        addMouseListener(this);   
    }
    public static Drawing getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
            instance =  new Drawing();
         return instance;

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    { 
         super.paintComponent(g);  

         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
         if(grid == null)
         {
            Toolkit toolkit =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
            Dimension dim = toolkit.getScreenSize();
            grid = (BufferedImage)(this.createImage(dim.width,dim.height));
            gc = grid.createGraphics();
            gc.setColor(Color.RED);
            BufferedImage grid;
            Graphics2D gc;
         }
         g2.drawImage(grid, null, 0, 0);
    }
public void draw()
{
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)getGraphics();
    int w = x2 - x1;
    if (w<0)
    w = w *(-1);
    int h = y2-y1;
    if (h<0)
    h=  h*(-1);
    gc.setColor(Menu.bgColor);
    switch(Main.choice)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            removeMouseMotionListener(instance);
            if (Menu.stroke == 0)
                gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke (1));
                if (Menu.stroke == 1)
                gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke (3));
                if (Menu.stroke == 2)
                gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke (6));
            gc.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            repaint();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            removeMouseMotionListener(instance);
            check();
            gc.drawRect(x1, y1, w, h);
            gc.fillRect(x1, y1, w, h);
            repaint();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            removeMouseMotionListener(instance);
            check();
            gc.drawOval(x1, y1, w, h);
            repaint();
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            removeMouseMotionListener(instance);
            check();
            gc.drawOval(x1, y1, w, h);
            gc.fillOval(x1, y1, w, h);
            repaint();
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            removeMouseMotionListener(instance);
            check();
            gc.drawRect(x1, y1, w, h);
            repaint();
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            removeMouseMotionListener(instance);
            repaint();
            Color temp = gc.getColor();
            gc.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            gc.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            gc.setColor(temp);
            repaint();
            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            removeMouseMotionListener(instance);
            gc.setColor(Menu.bgColor);
            break;
        }
        case 8:
        {
            FoE = 0;
            addMouseMotionListener(instance);
            break;
        }
        case 10:
        {
            FoE = 1;
            addMouseMotionListener(instance);
            break;
        }

    }
}


    public void check()
    {
        if (Menu.stroke == 0)
            gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke (1));
            if (Menu.stroke == 1)
            gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke (3));
            if (Menu.stroke == 2)
            gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke (6));


        if (x1 > x2)
        {
            int z = 0;
            z = x1;
            x1 = x2;
            x2 =z;
        }
        if (y1 > y2)
        {
            int z = 0;
            z = y1;
            y1 = y2;
            y2 = z;
        }
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        repaint();
        Color temp = gc.getColor();
        gc.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        gc.setColor(temp);
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){ }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){ 
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
    {
        x1 = evt.getX();
        y1= evt.getY();
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt)
    {
        x2 = evt.getX();
        y2 = evt.getY();
        removeMouseMotionListener(instance);
        draw();
    }


    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        check();
        if (FoE == 0)
        {

        Color c = gc.getColor();
        gc.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        gc.drawOval(me.getX(), me.getY(), eraserWidth, eraserHeight);
        gc.fillOval(me.getX(), me.getY(), eraserWidth, eraserHeight);
        gc.setColor(c);
        repaint();
        }
        else if (FoE == 1)
        {
         gc.setColor(gc.getColor());
         gc.drawOval(me.getX(), me.getY(), eraserWidth, eraserHeight);
         gc.fillOval(me.getX(), me.getY(), eraserWidth, eraserHeight);
         repaint();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0)
    {

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested your code but it looks like you're trying to add add [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) to your `JPanel` (Drawing). It should be the other way around you should add the `JPanel` to the [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) and then add the [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) to the content pane of the frame:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(Drawing.getInstance());
getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

[How to use JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the getPreferredSize() method of your Drawing class to return the size of the BufferedImages.

Scrollbars only appear when the preferred size of the component added to the scroll pane is greater than the size of the scroll pane.